# different content based on browser version?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, content-management-system, browser, dotnetnuke

Is it possible to display different content within a CMS (DNN) based on the browser the user is using? For example, IF IE 7 then display content 1

IE7 doesnt like image maps that well and id rather just show the user a static image of the flow chart i have made.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
Special instructions for IE 7 here
<![endif]-->
```

I would like to code some jquery to delete contents of the div class within the content pane (for that page, so checks for the file extension process.aspx) and then enable the image in the hidden div. << thats my theory?

1. detect which browser (if ie7 then:
2. delete content from content pane (checking the url for process.aspx)
3. enable the hidden div using `display:block`)

Comment: So, you want to detect the browser the user uses using JS, that's it?

Comment: added some more information in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `jQuery.browser` method:

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version == '7.0') {
      $('#content').show();
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: I had some problems with the `jQuery.browser` method. I finally prefer to use a CSS-based browser detection.

Answer (score 1):

Here a JS method to get IE version (returns `-1` if not IE):

```
function isUndefined(e) {
    return typeof e === "undefined";
}

function getIEVersion() {
    var style = document.body.style;
    var version = -1;
    if(!isUndefined(style.scrollbar3dLightColor)) {
        if (!isUndefined(style.opacity)) version = 9;
        else if (!isUndefined(style.msBlockProgression)) version = 8;
        else if (!isUndefined(style.msInterpolationMode)) version = 7;
        else if (!isUndefined(style.textOverflow)) version = 6;
        else version = 5;
    }
    return version;
}
```

Then, using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    if(getIEVersion() == 7) {
        $('#content-pane').hide();
        $('#hidden-div').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly you could just do this with CSS.

Have you two pieces of content

```
<div class="ForEveryone">
<!-- Your stuff here -->
</div>

<div class="ForIE7">
<!-- Code for less helpful browser here -->
</div>
```

Then by default have css to do

```
.ForIE7 { display: none; }
```

Then with an IE 7 specific style sheet change it to be

```
.ForEveryone { display: none; }
.ForIE7 { display: block; }
```

No need to go javascript for this one.